# Yii2 advanced на разных поддоменах?

Tags: php, yii2

Как разместить одно приложение Yii2 advanced на разных поддоменах.
К примеру:

```
frontend -> site.ru | backend -> admin.site.ru
```

Answer (score 1):

Для каждого поддомена, в настройках web сервера вам необходимо прописать DOCUMENT_ROOT на соответствующие папки шаблона.

Для site.ru

```
/path/to/project/frontend/web/
```

Для admin.site.ru

```
/path/to/project/backend/web/
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md#preparing-application

Вам нужно будет в место backend.dev прописать свой admin.site.ru